# How can I add a Cisco sg500x into an existing stack

Tags: cisco, switch

I have 3 Cisco sg500x-48 switches. All three switches were working correctly in a stack, but a user decided to re-cable the server toom. Since the re-cabling, the second switch will not re-join the stack.

I have stack designed in a ring using twinax from s2 - s1. No matter what I do, I cannot get the the second unit to rejoin the stack. It remains as stack ID 1 as master when the stack already has a master.

I have tried changing Twinax cables, different combinations of ports, reboots and even a factory reset.

Any troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I didn't break it; I'm not fixing it." Why is a user allowed access to recable the server room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it turns out that the third switch had a hardware issue. A replacement was delivered and everything was restored.

Answer (score 1):

Have you reset all involved switches, or just the one that won't join the stack?

If the site can deal with the down time.  I would reset the configs, disable all other ports on the switches except the stacking ports and your management port.  Then bring them back online and config the stacking.

Also, I would request that the "user" be summarily executed as an abject lesson to others!!! ;)